# Type of hops in Festival Pride of London Porter

Tags: hops

Can anyone tell me what hops are in the Festival Pride of London Porter Beer Kit.
I tasted what was left in the dry hop packet and I realy liked the taste.
I would like to find out what the hops are so I can use them in my own Beer.

Thanks all and stay safe.
John

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentionned anywhere on the web what the dry hop is.

If you can buy small hop packs at your local brew store, try buying the smallest amount of **Fuggles** or **East Kent Goldings** and then compare the smells.

I am suggesting those two hops, since I know they are used in Porters, but it could be any other, like: Glacier, Bullion or Northern Brewer...

Comment: Hi and thank you Philippe. I had a look around and cant find anything ether.Thanks for the suggestions you gave if it helps narow it down a bit the hops had an almost citrus taste not to bitter.I tasted the hop dust left in the packet after dropping them in. Thanks for your time replying. John